# Grep match only the exact string in the line

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm trying to grep for the word `OK` from the output of the below command

`valtool --validate <filename>` which throws below outputs

If success --> `<filename>: layers signatures val OK` & If failure--> `<filename>: layers signatures val NOT OK`

```
log='/home/files/rapid.so: layers signatures NOT OK'
~$ echo $log
/home/files/rapid.so: layers signatures NOT OK

~$ echo $log |grep -w 'OK' ;echo $?
/home/files/rapid.so: layers signatures NOT OK
0
```

Ideally, it should return `1` as per the requirement. I tried other options suggested on this forum but nothing helped.
I'm looking to get a return value of `0` if only `OK` is matched, else `1`.

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: can't you do `valtool --validate <filename>; echo $?`?

Comment: How about  `grep -E 'signatures +OK'`?

Comment: @user1934428 : Nice, I dint think of  `+`. Great

Comment: BTW, it does not make sense to store your file into a variable `log` and then spawn a `grep` child process. Better grep it directly: `if grep ....; then; ...`. But *if* you need a variable, then don't use `grep` to check it, but something like `[[ $log =~ signatures' '+OK ]]`

Comment: @user1934428 : No, Im not storing in a variable, just for the representation sake ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So invert NOT OK.

```
! grep "NOT OK$" <<<"$log"; echo $?
```

Comment: because of your nice idea 1++

Answer (score 0):

check this out :

```
echo "$log" | grep -w 'NOT OK' >/dev/null && echo 1 || echo 0
```

and make it a simple script :

```
log=$(valtool --validate <filename>)

if echo "$log" | grep -w 'NOT OK' >/dev/null; then
    echo "Validation failed"
    exit 1
else
    echo "Validation successful"
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Friends who give me negative ratings should be kind enough to explain why they gave me a negative rating so that I can address the issue!

Comment: I upvoted everything.